# How can execute MyButton.Command.Open before MyButton.Click event?

Tags: wpf, events, button, command

A button can use `Command.Open` property and `Click` event. But `Button.Click` event executes before `Button.Command.Open`. Since my `Button.Click` event code and `Button.Command.Open` code is connected with each other, I need `Button.Command.Open` to execute first and then `Button.Click` event to execute after that. How cab this be possible? Any solution?

Thanks and sorry because my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to find an event that fires before the `click` event, like the `PreviewMouseDown` event, and call your implementation of Open there.